# How can i check if an image link have width and height more than 1000 in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to make a function that after i paste one link in one input check if the image of this link have width and height more than 1000 and the format is JPG.

I try to do this way:

**HTML:**

```
<input (change)="verificaImagemValida(1, produto.foto_prin_1)" [(ngModel)]="produto.foto_prin_1" required type="text" name="foto_prin_1" id="foto_prin_1" class="form-control">
```

**TS:**

```
img = new Image();

verificaImagemValida(fotoAlvo: number, linkAlvo: string){

    console.log(linkAlvo);

    this.img.src = linkAlvo;

        if(this.img.width < 1000 || this.img.height < 1000 || !this.img.src.match(/jpg/)){
          this.toastrService.showToast(false,"Ops, temos um problema", "Imagem "+fotoAlvo+" deve ter 1000x1000px no formato JPG!");
          if(fotoAlvo == 1){
            this.produto.foto_prin_1 = null;
          }
        }
```

The first time that i paste the link that have a image with width e height more than 1000 and jpg the function shows the showToast function becausse the img.width and img.height have value 0. When i try to paste the same link in the input, this works properly. Why have wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're trying to get the image width of a empty image.

When you do `this.img.src = linkAlvo`, the image starts loading, but it takes a while.

You have to wait the image to load to verify its dimensions. The image element has a `load` event

```
img.onload = () => {
    if(this.img.width < 1000){
        ....
    }
}
```

So your code should be like:

```
img = new Image();

verificaImagemValida(fotoAlvo: number, linkAlvo: string){

    img.onload = () => {

        if(this.img.width < 1000 || this.img.height < 1000 || !this.img.src.match(/jpg/)){
          this.toastrService.showToast(false,"Ops, temos um problema", "Imagem "+fotoAlvo+" deve ter 1000x1000px no formato JPG!");
          if(fotoAlvo == 1){
            this.produto.foto_prin_1 = null;
          }
        }

    }

    this.img.src = linkAlvo;

}
```

The load event should be set before the image url, so you don't miss the loading event, in case it happens super fast, before defining the event.

I couldn't test this snippet, so it may have a few changes, but this is the main part you were missing.